# allowing users to switch text boxes with enter or arrow key in a visual studio

Tags: c#, user-interface, textbox

I'm making a simple Windows Forms Application program in visual studio 2015 using C# that takes clock in and out times, then calculates the time when a calculate button is hit, and displays the result in a separate box. Another button adds the time to a running total. It gets tedious clicking on each box back and forth. Is there a way that I can make it easier for users to switch between boxes rather than clicking between them each time, like pressing enter, or the arrow key to switch between textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, control has a property called "tab index" this can be used for setting the index. you can set it through property window or directly in c# (in case your controls are generated dynamically through code).

[image]

Comment: @BlakeThompson It's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

set the tab Index property according to your choice

```
textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
textBox3.TabIndex = 2;
```

or you can do it in design view

[image]